# Remove single quotes from each item in python list

Tags: python

What is the best way to remove single quotes in a python list?

I have the following input:

```
['"A","B","C",False,False',
'"A","B","C",False,False',
'"A","B","C",False,False']
```

But i want the following output:

```
 ["A","B","C",False,False, 
  "A","B","C",False,False, 
  "A","B","C",False,False]
```

Comment: what have u tried so far? is that a list or a string representation of a list?

Comment: Your questions is missing the point of your problem. This looks like you're reading lines in from a comma separated file without formatting them so they're being read in as a string for each line. There's plenty of libraries to help reading csv files. You could try pandas.read_csv(), which is my go to.

Comment: Do You mean to remove just all occurences of ' not " or remove all occurences of quotes that are not paired? For example remove quote from False' but to leave quotes in 'False' ?

Comment: @RoshaniMS edit your questions and add the code you have tried please.

Comment: Is your input coming from a call to splitlines()? Perhaps you should use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv) instead?

Answer (score 0):

***Your function (modified):***

```
def f1(database, table, lst):
    print("   processing mapping list...")
    rows = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        
        sublist = []
        sublist.append(database)
        sublist.append(table)
        sublist.append(lst[i][0].split(':')[0])
        sublist.append(lst[i][1]["a"])
        sublist.append(lst[i][1]["b"])

        rows.append(sublist)
    
    rows = [item for subl in rows for item in subl]
    rows = json.dumps(rows)
    return rows
```